# Rails Nested Form updating with Ajax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

Inside a game, I have a 10x10 grid with 100 squares and I am trying to make a button for a square that when clicked changes the square's :user_id to the current_user id.

**games/show.html.erb**

```
<% @squares.each_slice(10) do |slice| %>
        <% slice.each do |s| %>
            <%= div_for s, class: 'sq' do %>
                <%= s.boardposition %>
                <%= button_to buy_path(s), remote: true, method: :put %>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**games_controller.rb**

```
def show
    require 'enumerator'
    @user = current_user
    @game = Game.find(params[:id])
    @squares = Square.where(game_id:@game.id).all
end
```

**squares_controller.rb**

```
def buy
    @square = Square.find(square_params)

    respond_to do |format|
        format.js
        if @square.update_attributes(user_id: current_user.id)
            format.html {redirect_to squares_path}
        else
            format.html {redirect_to :back}
        end
    end
end

private

def square_params
    params.require(:square).permit(:xvalue, :yvalue, :user_id, :game_id, :boardposition)
end
```

**Game.rb**

```
has_many :squares
has_and_belongs_to_many :users

validates :roomname, :roomtype, :teamone, :teamtwo, :gamedate, :squareprice, 
:maxsquares, :q1pay, :q2pay, :q3pay, :q4pay, presence: true

accepts_nested_attributes_for :squares
```

**Square.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :game
```

**User.rb**

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :games
has_many :squares

accepts_nested_attributes_for :squares
```

**routes**

```
 resources :games, :users, :squares

 get '/games/:id/join/' => 'games#join', as: :join
 get '/games/:id/buy/' => 'squares#buy', as: :buy

 match '/games/:id/', to: 'squares#buy', via: [:post]
```

The error I'm getting when I click to buy a square is "ActionController::ParameterMissing in SquaresController#buy" Param not found: square.

I have tried for a while to figure this out and I believe my routes are correct now but I am having trouble passing the param. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing in the square object

```
def square_params
**params.require(:square)**.permit(:xvalue, :yvalue, :user_id, :game_id, :boardposition)
end
```

Either provide the square object somehow, via a form, or remove the strong parameters.

Comment: Is there any way to pass the square object in '<%= button_to buy_path(s), remote: true, method: :put %>'? Or else I'm not sure on how to make a form for the 's' object since it's already nested from the squares array